# Why is my pd.read_table pulling non-table values and putting everything in one column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, email, parsing

My current code scans through my emails and *should* search for a table in the emails. Once it finds the table, I want it to return the tables into a CSV file. Currently, the code scans this email:

[image]

And here's the text form:

```
Take a look here:

PO #    Line #  Seq Date
POO777777   77  7   7/7/2022
POO555555   55  5   5/5/2022
POO444444   44  4   4/4/2022
POO222222   22  2   2/2/2022

Best,
```

Which returns this into the CSV:

[image]

When I would like it to return this (without the non-table text and formatted like this):

[image]

Here is my current code:

```
with open("data.csv", "w") as f_out:
    writer = csv.writer(f_out)

    for i in range(messages, messages-N, -1):
        # fetch the email message by ID
        res, msg = imap.fetch(str(i), "(RFC822)")
        for response in msg:
            if isinstance(response, tuple):
                # parse a bytes email into a message object
                msg = email.message_from_bytes(response[1])
                # decode the email subject
                subject, encoding = decode_header(msg["Subject"])[0]
                if isinstance(subject, bytes):
                    # if it's a bytes, decode to str
                    subject = subject.decode(encoding)
                # decode email sender
                From, encoding = decode_header(msg.get("From"))[0]
                if isinstance(From, bytes):
                    From = From.decode(encoding)
                print("Subject:", subject)
                print("From:", From)
             
                for part in msg.walk():
                    # extract content type of email
                    content_type = part.get_content_type()
                    content_disposition = str(part.get("Content-Disposition"))
                    payload = part.get_payload(decode=True)
                    if payload is None:
                        continue
                    body = payload.decode()   
                    subjectt = subject
                    bodyy = body
                    pattern = re.compile(
                        r"([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][0-9]+) Line ([0-9]+) Seq ([0-9]+) ([0-9]+/[0-9]+/[0-9]+)"
                        )                    
                 
                    EMAIL_ADDRESS = '***@outlook.com'
                    EMAIL_PASSWORD = '***'
                  
                    try: 
                        datafile = io.StringIO(body.replace(' #','#')) # eliminate spaces in headers
                        pd.read_table(datafile, sep='\s+').to_csv('data.csv', index=False)
                    except:
                        sender_email = username
                        receiver_email = "***@gmail.com"
                        password = "***"
                        message = 'Subject: {}\n\n{}'.format(subject, bodyy)
                        server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp-mail.outlook.com', 587)
                        server.starttls()
                        server.login(sender_email, password)
                        server.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email, message)
                        print("email sent ツ".title())
                    break

imap.close()
imap.logout()
```

Comment: Nothing in your code "searches for a table in the email". All you're doing is trying to read the whole email body as a table after removing spaces before `#` characters. It looks like you may have a regex pattern made to find table lines, but it never actually gets used... What is your actual question?

Comment: Does the email have an html form, or only a text form?

Comment: @BeRT2me originally, my code searched for a pattern in the text, but I want to change it to search for a table in the text (as the emails are in text form). I want to adjust my code so that it searches for a table in my emails and copies them into a csv. let me know if that helps

Comment: Look into if you can get the message body in html. If you can you want to check that the table is in a <table> tag. If it is you may be able to use Pandas .read_html() to load the data into a table format then use pandas .to_csv(). If its not in a table tag you're going to need to find some sort of pattern